# gRPC: How to Add Many Services to NettyServer

Tags: netty, grpc

To provide a gRPC service, I need to implement a Netty server, and add my (gRPC) service to it. In Java I did:

```
Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port).addService(RetrieveServiceGrpc.bindService(new RetrieveServiceImpl()))
            .build().start();
```

In case I have many services, I may have something like:

```
.addService(....) //1st service
.addService(....) // 2nd service
.addService(....)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? (e.g: through some configuration that adds all the services under some folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, multiple calls to `addService()` would be the suggested way of setting of a server. It is generally important which services are implemented and adding new services is somewhat infrequent, so having them listed explicitly isn't too bad of an idea.

gRPC could improve support for dependency injection frameworks to inject the services, such as adding a `addServices(Set)`. However, gRPC needs to take an impartial approach since there are multiple competing DI frameworks and developers can feel strongly about their preference. If you have a suggestion on improving the DI experience, feel free to [make an issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/new).

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the `@GRpcService` annotation on your service class (RetrieveServiceImpl) using [grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter):

```java
@GRpcService
public static class GreeterService extends GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase {
    @Override
    public void sayHello(GreeterOuterClass.HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<GreeterOuterClass.HelloReply> responseObserver) {
        final GreeterOuterClass.HelloReply.Builder replyBuilder = GreeterOuterClass.HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello " + request.getName());
        responseObserver.onNext(replyBuilder.build());
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

This takes care of calling the `addService` method among other things ([details](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter/blob/c2d27ddef5b46df67f2a177168752474da47db07/grpc-spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/org/lognet/springboot/grpc/GRpcServerRunner.java#L78)).

Documentation on GitHub : https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter/tree/master#show-case